# jquery ready function: script not detecting a function

Tags: jquery, function, document-ready

There is a web page with place holder (a normal div). Via ajax calls I am loading a `<form>` and a `<script>` into the place holder. The script contains necessary javascript to initialize the form (i.e. for e.g. disable the controls so as to make form read-only, etc). Here is a piece of code I have; it works, but the commented part doesn't work. Because the script engine cannot find the object tristate_DisableControl which is a function in one of those scripts I call via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //    $('#site_preferences_content div').each(function() {
    //        if (typeof (window.tristate_DisableControl) == 'undefined') {

    //            if (typeof (window.console) != 'undefnied')
    //                console.log((new Date()).toTimeString() + ' not logable');

    //            pausecomp(1000);

    //        }
    //        else
    //            tristate_DisableControl(this);
    //    }); //end $('#site_prefrences_content div').each()

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#site_preferences_content div').each(function() { tristate_DisableControl(this); })
    }, 1000);

});
```

I thought by the time $(document).ready() executes the DOM will be properly loaded...

Comment: where do you load your scripts? provide the code and/or markup please.

Comment: i apologize to all. The issue was with placement of the scripts. There are 2 scripts included in the page I call via ajax; one of them had the definition for tristate_DisableControl. The other script made use of this function. The problem was because of placing the 2nd script first followed by the 1st script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ready` event happens when the page is finished loading. It doesn't wait for asynchronous AJAX calls to complete.

To run the code once the extra content is loaded, you use the callback of the `load` method. Example:

```
$('#site_preferences_content').load('content.html', function() {
  $('#site_preferences_content div').each(function() {
    tristate_DisableControl(this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly, but if the declaration of `tristate_DisableControl` is returned by an AJAX call, then no, `DOMReady` does not wait until all AJAX calls are executed (after all, how could it possibly know how many AJAX calls will be made?)

You  have to use the `success` / `complete` callback of the AJAX function to find out when it has finished loading.

Comment: tristate_DisableControl is not returned by an AJAX call. To be specific my ajax call gets a page with a line of code saying `<script src="tristate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` --> this contains the definition for tristate_DisableControl

Answer (score 0):

Document ready event fires when whole document is loaded, which excludes scripts loaded using ajax, because if that wasn't the case, ready event would probably never fire if your script keeps making ajax calls.

You should use callbacks on ajax loading methods for this.